# Error when playing a video in VideoView in android

Tags: android, media-player, android-videoview

When I use the following code to play `mp4` video file in android

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

//  vvIntro = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vvIntro);
    VideoView vvIntro = new VideoView(this);
    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.intro); 

    vvIntro.setVideoURI(video);
    setContentView(vvIntro);
    vvIntro.start();
}
```

I got the following error ?

```
04-29 23:04:38.740: E/MediaPlayer(25435): Unable to to create media player
04-29 23:04:38.748: D/MediaPlayer(25435): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
04-29 23:04:38.748: E/MediaPlayer(25435): error (1, -2147483648)
04-29 23:04:38.818: E/MediaPlayer(25435): Error (1,-2147483648)
04-29 23:04:38.818: D/VideoView(25435): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

what does it mean ?

Comment: Any Luck? Where you able to resolve this?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this code   

int raw_id = getResources().getIdentifier(Filename_without_extension, "raw",getPackageName());

String PATH="android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+raw_id;
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(PATH));
mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(Classname.this));
mVideoView.requestFocus();
mVideoView.start();
```